# Create derrived instance from base in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a TPT (*Type-Per-Table*) hierarchy:

```
public class StorageEntry
{
   public int StorageEntryId { get; set; }
   // other props
}

[Table("PhotoStorageEntries")]
public class PhotoStorageEntry : StorageEntry
{
    public int SomeFK { get; set; }
}
```

Consider, I have existing row of `StorageEntry` of id `**1**`
Now, I would like to transform that `StorageEntry` into `PhotoStorageEntry`.

I've tried:

```
dbContext.AddOrCreate(new PhotoStorageEntry 
               { 
                   StorageEntryId = 1, // existing key
                   SomeFK = 20
               });
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

UnFortunately, EF complains about missing other, required properties of `StorageEntry`. What can I do?

Comment: What is the excact message that EF give you? If thoses properties are required then you must fill them before saving your data.

Comment: By the way Save is not a method from DbCOntext.

Comment: @CodeNotFound yeep, I meant `SaveChanges()`. There are validation errors, because required properties from `StorageEntry` are not fiilled. Buy I want to avoid to fetch existing row and rewrite values.

Comment: Because it is a new entity you must fill all required properties before calling savechange methode

Comment: So, I need to load old entity, rewrite all props and the save derivered instances? I thought it could less complicated.. Especially that from the database side it's just row in table, where there are two columns..